# Changing the struct names in the returned json data in Golang according to the incoming data

Tags: json, go, struct

I am doing a code analysis project with Bandit. This project returns me a different json each time. The names of the py files under Metrics change in each project analysis, how should I proceed when I want to convert it as a struct?

My Struct:

```
type LogOutput struct {
    Errors      []interface{} `json:"errors"`
    GeneratedAt time.Time     `json:"generated_at"`
    Metrics     Metrics       `json:"metrics"`
    Results     []Results     `json:"results"`
}
type MetricData struct {
    CONFIDENCEHIGH      float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.HIGH"`
    CONFIDENCELOW       float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.LOW"`
    CONFIDENCEMEDIUM    float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM"`
    CONFIDENCEUNDEFINED float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED"`
    SEVERITYHIGH        float64 `json:"SEVERITY.HIGH"`
    SEVERITYLOW         float64 `json:"SEVERITY.LOW"`
    SEVERITYMEDIUM      float64 `json:"SEVERITY.MEDIUM"`
    SEVERITYUNDEFINED   float64 `json:"SEVERITY.UNDEFINED"`
    Loc                 int     `json:"loc"`
    Nosec               int     `json:"nosec"`
}

type Totals struct {
    CONFIDENCEHIGH      float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.HIGH"`
    CONFIDENCELOW       float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.LOW"`
    CONFIDENCEMEDIUM    float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM"`
    CONFIDENCEUNDEFINED float64 `json:"CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED"`
    SEVERITYHIGH        float64 `json:"SEVERITY.HIGH"`
    SEVERITYLOW         float64 `json:"SEVERITY.LOW"`
    SEVERITYMEDIUM      float64 `json:"SEVERITY.MEDIUM"`
    SEVERITYUNDEFINED   float64 `json:"SEVERITY.UNDEFINED"`
    Loc                 int     `json:"loc"`
    Nosec               int     `json:"nosec"`
}
type Metrics struct {
    MetricData []MetricData `json:"metric"`
    Totals     Totals       `json:"_totals"`
}
type Results struct {
    Code            string `json:"code"`
    Filename        string `json:"filename"`
    IssueConfidence string `json:"issue_confidence"`
    IssueSeverity   string `json:"issue_severity"`
    IssueText       string `json:"issue_text"`
    LineNumber      int    `json:"line_number"`
    LineRange       []int  `json:"line_range"`
    MoreInfo        string `json:"more_info"`
    TestID          string `json:"test_id"`
    TestName        string `json:"test_name"`
}
```

Json Data:

```
{
  "errors": [],
  "generated_at": "2022-08-26T10:34:21Z",
  "metrics": {
    "/code/run.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 12,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/__init__.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 0,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/app.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 31,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/__init__.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 0,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/course.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 41,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/mark.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 31,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/review.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 30,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/student.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 1.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 1.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 38,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/dao/user.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 1.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 1.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 34,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/middlewares.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 60,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/routes.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 24,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/schema/__init__.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 0,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/schema/config.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 19,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/schema/forms.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 14,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/services/__init__.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 0,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/services/db.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 16,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/services/redis.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 13,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/utils/__init__.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 0,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/utils/auth.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 25,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/utils/jinja2.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 13,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "/code/sqli/views.py": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 138,
      "nosec": 0
    },
    "_totals": {
      "CONFIDENCE.HIGH": 1.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.LOW": 1.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.MEDIUM": 0.0,
      "CONFIDENCE.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.HIGH": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.LOW": 0.0,
      "SEVERITY.MEDIUM": 2.0,
      "SEVERITY.UNDEFINED": 0.0,
      "loc": 539,
      "nosec": 0
    }
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "code": "41     async def create(conn: Connection, name: str):\n42         q = (\"INSERT INTO students (name) \"\n43              \"VALUES ('%(name)s')\" % {'name': name})\n44         async with conn.cursor() as cur:\n",   
      "filename": "/code/sqli/dao/student.py",
      "issue_confidence": "LOW",
      "issue_severity": "MEDIUM",
      "issue_text": "Possible SQL injection vector through string-based query construction.",
      "line_number": 42,
      "line_range": [
        42,
        43
      ],
      "more_info": "https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b608_hardcoded_sql_expressions.html",
      "test_id": "B608",
      "test_name": "hardcoded_sql_expressions"
    },
    {
      "code": "40     def check_password(self, password: str):\n41         return self.pwd_hash == md5(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()\n",
      "filename": "/code/sqli/dao/user.py",
      "issue_confidence": "HIGH",
      "issue_severity": "MEDIUM",
      "issue_text": "Use of insecure MD2, MD4, MD5, or SHA1 hash function.",
      "line_number": 41,
      "line_range": [
        41
      ],
      "more_info": "https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklists/blacklist_calls.html#b303-md5",
      "test_id": "B303",
      "test_name": "blacklist"
    }
  ]
}
```

All data except Metrics are currently converted as structs, but I need to automate the naming here since the name.py data changes in each repo examined. I'm stuck on this, can you help?

Comment: You probably want to change `MetricData []MetricData` to `MetricData map[string]MetricData` in your `LogOutput`—because in the JSON document, "metrics" is an object which "maps" file names to other JSON objects (with metrics).

Comment: But to be honest, I fail to parse the question: it does not sound like [an MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean). I really have no idea how to interpret «…I need to automate the naming here since the name.py data changes in each repo examined.»—it simply makes no sense to me.

Comment: When I examine different repos, the field names in the metrics under the json data returned to me are different, for example code/test.py, code/unit-test.py or code/acsasf.py when another repo is examined. Since these change each time, I want to throw the json data into the struct. This is exactly my problem @kostix

Comment: @MertÖzler use a map as pointed out by kostix

Comment: @MertÖzler And if you want a slice you'd need to declare a new slice type, have it implement the json.Unmarshaler interface, and have that implementation use *a map*.

Comment: @MertÖzler, OK, that makes sense. Note that what you're dealing with here is a plain JSON object which has file names as its field names and other JSON objects as the values of these fields. Conceptually, you can interpret JSON objects as Go's `struct`s—if the fields of such objects have fixed names,—or as Go's `map`s. Your case calls for maps because the set of "keys"—names of fields of those JSON objects—is arbitrary in each case.

Comment: Can you show me how to decode this for me? When I write it with map, the metric data is empty, probably because I haven't written a code like `json:"field_name"`, I can't access it. How should I decode the struct here relative to JSON? Thank you. @kostix

Comment: @MertÖzler, <https://go.dev/play/p/1w-tSJLJ1Rp>

Comment: I undo the deletion, I'm looking forward to your reply.. @trincot